# Label Updating issue in Sencha Touch1.0

Tags: sencha-touch

I need to update the label value after the refresh, When i tried labelEI.update('new value'); following doLayout() it showing an error

Answer (score 0):

Which sencha-touch version are you using?

In the latest version "update()" method is deprecated, use "setHtml()" instead.